# Loopback cannot send dynamic values in email

Tags: javascript, email, loopbackjs, strongloop, nodemailer

I have a contact form where i can able to save the data in the database using loopback3. I need to send an email also so i have added the email connector for this module, but i can able to send only the static values in the mail. How to get the dynamic values in contact.js file and send through email.

contact.json

```
{
  "name": "contact",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "email": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "subject": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "message": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "inserted_date": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

contact.js

```
'use strict';
const app = require('../../server/server');
module.exports = function(Contact) {
    Contact.afterRemote('create', function(context, remoteMethodOutput, next) { 
        next(); 

Contact.app.models.Email.send({ 
    to: 'lakshmipriya.l@company.com', 
    from: 'lakshmipriya.l@gmail.com', 
    subject: 'my subject', 
    text: 'my text', 
    html: 'my <em>html</em>' 
    }, function(err, mail) { 
    console.log('email sent!'); 
    cb(err); 
    }); 
    }); 

};
```

How to send an email with dynamic values, can anyone tell me how to fetch the contact.json values and send to contact.js file .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the model instance through the context object, which transports the data. You can read more on it here: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Remote-hooks.html#ctxresult

So to send the email to the contact that has been created:

```
Contact.app.models.Email.send({ 
 to: context.result.email, 
 from: 'lakshmipriya.l@gmail.com', 
 subject: 'my subject', 
 text: 'my text', 
 html: 'my <em>html</em>' 
}, function(err, mail) { 
 console.log('email sent!'); 
 cb(err); 
 }); 
});
```